# Import a barcode from a barcodescanner to a web app and connecting to a SQL Server 2012 from a smart project

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-2012, motorola

I need to develop a web app mostly for a motorola mc 9090 symbol barcode scanner, my problem is this: can I pass the string that is read by the scanner directly to a text box in this app? I know that for a windows form app motorola emdk provides a onscan event that receives the barcode.

My second problem is: can I connect using an ado connection to a SQL Server 2012 from a smart project device, I know for sure you can do that for a SQL Server 2005 but will it work for a SQL Server 2012? or would I need a web api?

Comment: sorry it is 2012 i don't know what i was thinking.

Comment: Doesn't the scanner simply send the scanned string as keyboard input with a subordinate CRLF? If that's the case, wouldn't a simple textbox with an Enter-handler suffice? (at least that's the case for our scanners, we use in our wpf apps - we do not use any sdk for that scenario, but simply let the scanner act as a keyboard)

Comment: Where's the web-app running? On the scanner, on a pc to which the scanner is connected....?

Comment: thank you Andreas for your help.. i don't know, i don't have a device for testing yet, i have developed an app for this scanner it was a windows form app and i used an event called onscan for retrieving the code from the barcode scanner.

Comment: i should run on the scanner's browser since it has a windows mobile 6 os.